# Geany - make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I'm new to UNIX/Linux. Right now, I'm using Manjaro Linux (the KDE version) and when I try to compile my code, I always get this error (*****make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.*****). Google didn't help me at all. I'm so sorry if the question is repetitive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs9X2.png)

Comment: The problem appears to be that you're not trying to compile your code; you're trying to run make, but you have no Makefile.

Comment: Now I got the message: "compilation succesfully". But still, I can't run the program. same error. :(. Is there a way to fix this makefile error?